# How to add double quotes to lines in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file which is having around 100 email-ids(one in a line). I just want to add double quotes to each of email-id. I am preferably looking for a shell script.

Could someone please help me in getting this.

Comment: You can do `sed 's/.*/"&."/' file`

Comment: actually i want to do everything in an automated way...like in a bash script

Comment: So you found awk command below an **automated** bash script but `sed` wasn't :P

Comment: @anubhava plz don't mind, i agree that your solution is also correct, but i was looking for some script..

Comment: I didn't mind but was amused how awk command is a script but sed is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try awk

```
awk '{print "\x22"$0"\x22"}' inputfilename
```

in sed

```
sed 's/.*/"&"/g' inputfilename
```